# Bash completion with space key only if the line is empty

Tags: bash, bash-completion

I have the following bash script

```
cmd_complete () {
    make run
    echo -n "${PS1@P}" # print prompt again
}

complete -F cmd_complete -E

bind "Space:complete"
```

This script does the following:

- When pressing space in the terminal it triggers the terminal completion
- The terminal complete will execute the function `cmd_complete`
- The `cmd_complete` will run `make run` command then prints bash prompt again.

What is wrong:

- When typing a word in the terminal and press space it'll not print space
- this is because space is bound to `complete` function whether the bash line is empty or not.

What I would like to achieve is:

- To run `cmd_complete` when pressing space ONLY when the line is empty.

Documentation I checked but couldn't find what I need:

- [Complete shell command manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html)
- [Bash programmable completion documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion.html)

Comment: Can you omit `bind "Space:complete"` and just use `Esc+Esc`  to run `cmd_complete` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
my_cmd(){
    # short variable names are easier to read
    local -n ln=READLINE_LINE pt=READLINE_POINT

    # if line is not empty, just insert a space
    if [[ -n $ln ]]; then
        ln="${ln:0:pt} ${ln:pt}"
        (( pt++ ))
        return
    fi

    # do stuff here
    make run

    # no need to re-print the prompt
}

bind -x '" ":my_cmd'
```